# Convert a sqlite database toi a duckdb including tables , indices and views

Tags: r, split, duckdb

I have a large (250GB) sqlite database, containing huge tables, views and indices. To reduce the size (and probably the access speed), I am thinking about converting the db to a duckdb.

Is there an easy way of converting a sqlite db to a duckdb database?

I could re-write the creation of the database to use duckdb (in R), but would like to avoid this before I can see that there is an impact worth making the changes.

Comment: Are you using https://github.com/duckdblabs/sqlite_scanner/ to currently read it?